# OOP: understanding Abstraction

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance

I have gone through many articles and some Stack Overflow questions for better understanding of `abstraction` but am a little confused. This is what I have been reading: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600449/IntroductionplustoplusObjectplusOrientedplusProgra)

> Abstraction is "To represent the essential feature without
>   representing the background details."Abstraction lets you focus on
>   what the object does instead of how it does it.

Code given:

```
abstract class MobilePhone
}
    public void Calling();
    public void SendSMS();
}

public class Nokia1400 : MobilePhone
{

}

public class Nokia2700 : MobilePhone
{
    public void FMRadio();
    public void MP3();
    public void Camera();
}
```

My question is that when we inherit  `abstract class` don't we implement details in our sub classes?
calling() and sendSms() dont have any implementation in the super type so when we implement it in our sub class then we should know background details as well. So how is Abstraction actually working in this example?

**Edit** :if  you cam here for some help these guys gave best answers  :  Complexity  Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: In your Example it's simplay says that Calling and SendSms is a core functionality of MobilePhone in each phone it's a avlible so when your mobile is change you don't need to write a method for calling and sendmsg you can just use it from abstract class and no one can chnage it because abstract dosen't allow to create a object

Comment: @DhavalPatel and implementation details will be provided in these two methods right ?

Comment: yes you have to implemented those two method in your abstract class because if you non abstract method then you must have a implementation. basically abstract remove the code redudancy no need to write code again and again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are a couple of issues in your code.

- The abstract class does contain methods without a body and are not abstract, so this isn't valid. You should either make the methods abstract, or provide a body in them. When you want to have a body but you want to be able to override the method, the virtual keyword must be applied.
  So this are the choices that you have for your abstract class:

Methods without a body:

```
abstract class MobilePhone
{
    public abstract void Calling();
    public abstract void SendSMS();
}
```

Methods with a body that can be overriden:

```
abstract class MobilePhone
{
    public virtual void Calling()
    {
        // Code goes here.
    }

    public virtual void SendSMS()
    {
        // Code goes here.
    }
}
```

Methods with a body that cannot be overriden:

```
abstract class MobilePhone
{
    public void Calling()
    {
        // Code goes here.
    }

    public void SendSMS()
    {
        // Code goes here.
    }
}
```

Then there are a couple of more problems. Your abstract class does not provide a constructor which makes the object private by default, so your class Nokia1400 and Nokia2700 cannot inherit from the base class because the base class is less accessible than the abstract class.

Now, depending on how you created your abstracted class, the classes that implementes it must fullify some requirements:

- When your base class does contain abstract members, it should be implemented in your inheriting class.
- When your base class does contain virtual members, it should not be implemented in your inheriting class but it can be overidden if needed.

And than, your last class with not compile neither because it does contain methods without a body. Those kinds of methods are only allowed if they are abstract and then they must be in an abstract class.

Here's a sample based on your code:

```
public abstract class MobilePhone
{
    public virtual void Calling()
    {
        Console.Write("Calling");
    }

    public abstract void SendSMS();
}

public class Nokia1400 : MobilePhone
{
    public override void SendSMS()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending SMS from Nokia 1400.");
    }
}

public class Nokia2700 : MobilePhone
{
    public void FMRadio()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FM Radio");
    }

    public void MP3()
    {
        Console.Write("MP3");
    }

    public void Camera()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Camera");
    }

    public override void SendSMS()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending SMS from Nokia 2700.");
    }
}
```

So, a fair long post but I hope it helped.

Comment: this is great explanation , if  u have time u can also refer these corrections in this codeproject article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600449/IntroductionplustoplusObjectplusOrientedplusProgra

Comment: i mean u raised really  good points  (as u pointed out some issues that were in  code that cleared me  the whole idea) u can also suggest this in where i  got this article  from my aboive mentioned link.  your answer was more helpful than that article .it may help other who are going to  read that article in future

Comment: I'll what I can do because I don't event know i can suggest edits to an article on CodeProject and don't have an accout on it. If this article helped you understand the subject, consider to mark it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can have abstract methods and virtual methods

The abstract methods have to be be implemented by the extending class and do not have a body.

The Virtual methods do have a body but do not need to be overridden. If they are not, then the body of the base class' virtual method is executed.

There are some caveats but that is the main idea

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public abstract void MethodMustBeImplemented();
    public virtual void DoesNotHaveToBeOverwritten()
    {
      //Do WORk
    }
}


public class Implementor: MyBase
{

}
```

This will throw a compile time error as `MethodMustBeImplemented()` has not been overridden.

But the following is fine

```
public class Implementor: MyBase
{
    public override void MethodMustBeImplemented()
    {
      //Do WORk
    }
}
```

Comment: please confirm dont we need to implement all abstract/ non abstract methods when we have marked   class as abstract

Comment: in C#, only those marked as `abstract` need to be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Lets add missing details to your quote:

> Abstraction represents the essential feature [which client code needs]
>   without representing the background details [to client code]. [When
>   you use] Abstraction [it] lets you focus on what the object does
>   instead of how it does it [because you don't know which class
>   implemenets it].

I believe now its clear. You should look on abstraction from clients point of view, i.e. from code which will use your MobilePhone. Abstraction is not necessary *abstract* class (a little miss-leading term) - it can also be an interface.

Real-world example - when you act as *client* to TV set, you use *abstraction* of TV sets (there should be different channels, volume control etc), but you don't care which exact implementation of these abstraction was given to you (if all features of TV abstraction required by you are implemented). Client should be satisfied, and he should be kept away from details. I bet you just watching TV, not some particular Toshiba NX-42C?

Comment: missing details are really helpful ...!

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you have to differentiate between:

Abstract class & abstract method

Abstract class can never be instantiated,  it must be inherited by another class then the inheriting class will be instantiated.

Now back to abstract class: it can have two type of methods: 
- normal method ( as in your example calling and sendsms). Bec. These r normal methods, they are considered implemented with empty body, so the inheriting class will not need to implement them [that is what confuse you]

-abstract methods: these methods are prefixed with the key word "abstract" and once the key word abstract is there then the inheriting class SHOULD implement them

To clarify it more:
If methods calling() and sendingSms() we're prefixed with "abstract" Then it should be implemented

--

Now virtual method and overriding is another concept,  I may talk about it if you are still interested

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall,  implementing an abstract class, you fill in the body.

It's like a contract.

When you use that abstract class, implementing it, you agree to have those method signatures(that method name, those parameters, that return type), and those variables.

The benefit is that if a class implements it, you know that it(the class that implements it) can be communicated with in that way(it has those method names, those variables). So an abstract class is like the basis of an API.

Comment: Keep in mind that abstract class can have implementation details (or even have no abstract methods inside at all, just be declared as abstract to prevent instantiation), so calling abstract class "like the basis of an API" is not entirely accurate. It would be more accurate to use this description regarding an interface, because those are not intended to have any implementation details whatsoever.

Comment: @user3613916 ah yes, was only interface that I used then, and over a decade ago. I recall now abstract was similar though I must've hardly used it. good correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class C{
public abstract void met1();
public void met2(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

In abstraction you must implement bodyless methods of abstract class if you are extending abstract class while the methods which have their implementation in abstract class may or may not get `Overridden` in subclass.

So in above class if you extends `Class C` you **must** put implementation of `met1` in your class while `met2` is optional you can even override it if you want to.

```
@Override
public void met2(){
    super.met2();
}
```

---

So abstraction is actually Hiding the actual imlementation of SUBCLASS from the viewer who are concentrating on SUPERCLASS.

***FOR EXAMPLE:***

Consider class Dog which is abstract which has methods like `bark()` but the Classes which extends Dog will have their Own implementation for example you have class like BullDog which extends Dog.

Comment: So u mean  implementation details for these  two methods           public void Calling(); public void SendSMS() ;  will be provided in abstract class and that implementation will be used in sub classes ?

Comment: no (Body Less)declaration is there in abstract but implementation must be there in subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Since base class was declared as abstract, it cannot be instantiated, so you cannot call those abstract methods from base class, only from derived classes that do implement mentioned abstract class.

When you declare class as abstract, you say this class cannot be instantiated. Then you are allowed to declare abstract methods inside of a class, since you don't need implementation for them as these cannot be called anyway. Now though any non-abstract class deriving from your base class has to implement those methods to allow instantiation at all.